# String obfuscation

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem,
I need to convert a string of dotts and dashes to alphanumeric string using JavaScript, like so:

1. Replace the number of consecutive dots with a number
2. replace the number of consecutive dashes with the letter of the alphabet at that position

example: `... = 3, --.- = b1a, ..-. = 2a1`

Given string `../.-|--/..|-./-|.-.|---|..-|-...|.-..|.` should output -> `2/1A|B/2|A1/A|1A1|C|2A|A3|1A2|1`.

All the `|` and `/` needs to stay at their position untouched.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like below, iterating over each character using reduce, there should be a little scope to simplify the logic which I will work on!

```js
const input = '../.-|--/..|-./-|.-.|---|..-|-...|.-..|.';

const { res } = Array.prototype.reduce.call(input, (acc, c, index, inp) => {
    if (c === '.') {
      acc.dots++;
    } else if (c === '-') { 
      acc.dashes++;
    } 
    
    if ((c !== '.' || index === inp.length-1) && acc.dots) { 
      acc.res += String(acc.dots);
      acc.dots = 0;
    }
    if ((c !== '-' || index === inp.length-1) && acc.dashes) { 
      acc.res += String.fromCharCode(64 + acc.dashes);
      acc.dashes = 0;
    }
    if (c === "/" || c === "|") { 
      acc.res += c;
    }
    return acc;
}, { dots: 0, dashes: 0, res: "" });

console.log("Result:", res)
```

Comment: I think we can make this shorter suing something like `str.replace(/(\.+)([^\.])/g,function(parts) {  return (parts[1].length)+parts[2] })`